# Setting values to collection but not reference

Tags: java, collections, reference

I would be grateful if you help me with next problem.

I have such code:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(5);
list.add(7);
list.add(9);
Deque<List<Integer>> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.addLast(list);
list.add(11);
deque.addLast(list);
list.add(13);
deque.addLast(list);
deque.stream().forEach(System.out::println)
```

I need to get next result:

```
[5, 7, 9]
[5, 7, 9, 11]
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

However, real result is:

```
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

I researched this issue and found that the core problem is that collections in Java save not values but references so modifying objects after setting its to collections causes their modification in collections.

Is there a way to solve this problem and get result as I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add new copy of list to your deque everytime.:

```
Deque<List<Integer>> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.addLast(list.stream().toList());
list.add(11);
deque.addLast(list.stream().toList());
list.add(13);
deque.addLast(list.stream().toList());
deque.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

note : `toList()` is available from java16.

You can replace `list.stream().toList()` call with `list.stream().collect(Collectors.toList())` if you use java8+.

Comment: Thank you! It really works with collections.I have to use such approach to arrays too which contain objects of not primitive class (created manually). So the analogy `deque.addLast(Arrays.stream(array).toArray())` doesn't work because it returns objects of class Object instead of objects of necessary class. Casting of this result to array of necessary object causes _ClassCastException_. Could you please tell how to meet this problem with arrays?

Comment: `deque.addLast(Arrays.stream(array).toArray())` is failed because you are looking for `List` in Deque & not array.  I am not getting your above question you mentioned in comments. can you please rephrase it little bit.
Moreover, considering above is working for original question, can you please accept & upvote it in meanwhile while we can try to address your another question?  Thanks

Comment: Of course, done already. 
My another code is similar to this:
'Student student = new Student();
 Student student1 = new Student();
 Student[] array = new Student[2];
 array[0] = student;
 array[1] = student1;
 Deque<Student[]> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
 deque.addLast(array);
 array[0].setName("...");
 array[1].setName("...");
 deque.addLast(array);
 After modification of student and student 1 this objects are modified in the deque too. But I want to avoid it

Comment: For arrays you can use something like : 
`deque1.addLast(Arrays.stream(array).toArray(Student[]::new)` This is based on your example you have given above.

@Ensei

Comment: I tried to use such approach. But the data in deque is still modificated after modification student objects without adding its to deque.

Comment: I have verified it with normal Integer array & can see once you added one element, it is not modifying . May be better you can raise another question for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding the list directly to your dequeue, you could add a copy:

```java
Deque<List<Integer>> deque = new ArrayDeque<>();
deque.addLast(new ArrayList<>(list));
list.add(11);
deque.addLast(new ArrayList<>(list));
list.add(13);
deque.addLast(new ArrayList<>(list));
```